# Bind to Port 443 on Fedora

Tags: ubuntu, debian, fedora

I'm currently designing a website on Ubuntu and testing it with Tomcat 7. I wanted to run my site on port 443, so I installed authbind, because I don't want Tomcat running as root.

As I continue coding the site, I transfer all my files to a server running Fedora 16. My problem is, I can't figure out how to run Tomcat on port 443 on Fedora. From my understanding, authbind is only for Debian/Ubuntu.

Any ideas? I've heard that I can use Apache httpd in conjunction with Apache Tomcat, but I'm worried that would be slower than the speed my site requires.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would not try to bind tomcat on port 443.  Instead, I would use iptables to NAT incomming traffic on port 443 to the tomcat port.